# How to express cassandra cql's CONTAINS in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra

I couldn't find a way how to express this cql query in linq. We have a table with indexed tags collection field represented as set.I can use CONTAINS to select.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    ...
    tags set<text>,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX ON test (tags);
select * from test where tags CONTAINS 'tag';
```

But when i try to use this linq code it throws error.

```
[Serializable]
[Table("test")]
public class Test
{
    [PartitionKey]
    [Column("id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Column("tags")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; set; }
}

_table.Where(x=>x.Tags.Contains(tag))
```

> variable 'x' of type 'Test'
>   referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Comment: CQL `CONTAINS` is not supported yet in the Linq component of the driver.

Comment: Is this still the case?